# max_connections set to 500, Max_used_connections never go over 151

Tags: mysql, max-connections

I have this set in the mysql config file, rebooted, seems to be correct.

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "max_connections";
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| max_connections | 500   |
+-----------------+-------+
```

I have a load test against my server. This never get's above 151, server just gets real slow until the testing is done.

```
mysql> SHOW STATUS LIKE 'max_used_connections';
+----------------------+-------+
| Variable_name        | Value |
+----------------------+-------+
| Max_used_connections | 151   |
+----------------------+-------+
```

I have already put in every config option that supposedly will fix this. Will Max_used_connections ever go above 151?

ubuntu 16
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.33, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

been dinking around with this all day, thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Tell us more about the load test.  What probably happened...

The test succeeded in launching 151 threads at the 'same' time.  Those threads then fought with each other for CPU, disk, network, etc.  They were each given "equal" access to everything.

What does that lead to?  Well, imagine letting 151 customers into a small grocery store.  Each would be pushing there cart but bumping into other carts.  It would take 'forever' to finish one aisle and get to the next.

The net effect is *everyone* takes an abnormally long time to finish the task.  Have you learned anything about the load?  No.  The grocery store was *overloaded*.

Run the load test again, but with the "max threads" set to something like twice the number of CPUs.

Is it possible to have 500 connections?  Yes.  But only if they are not doing what the load test is designed to do:  pound on the database and do nothing else.

That is not realistic.  A web page, for example, will grab some data, build some HTML, wait for the user to input something, etc.  That is, a *realistic* load involves more than just hitting the database.

What was the goal of your load test?  Maybe we can help you get some real news instead of this fake news.

Comment: Using octoperf.com simulates simultaneous access to the server. Starts at 0 and ramps up to 200 simultaneous connections. Each connection accesses a page that references some info in the db. Reads only, it's a pretty basic test, however the max used connection count never goes over 151. The server is fine until this threshold but then is slow to respond until testing is over. The goal of my load test was to see if the max used connection count would ever go over 151. I don't understand your fake news comment. I'm asking for help for something I'm observing, there is nothing fake about it.

Comment: @ericl - Instead of 200, try 40.  See if it flows more smoothly and if it finishes more "jobs" in the same amount of time.  And see if `Max_used_connections` hits only 40.